# How do I tag a volume with the private IP address of the instance it is attached to using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, tags, ansible

I am trying to mount a bunch of volumes using Ansible's mounting module on numerous instances (with particular names) and I need a way to make sure that I can check that a volume that is being parsed through is going to the right instance to be mounted.

The issue that I have run into is that if I have two hosts and the instance information of those hosts (including volume IDs), it will try to mount all of the volumes to both hosts, when in reality I need a check that will prevent that.

I would like to be able to tag a volume with the IP address of the instance it is already attached to. I am able to do it with one instance, but it does not work with multiple instances...

With one instance:

```
- name: Tag the EBS Volumes
  hosts: datanodes
  gather_facts: False
  tags: tag
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/defaults.yml         
  tasks:
  - setup:
        filter: ansible_mounts

  - name: Gather datanodes instance instance_ids
    local_action:
        module: ec2_remote_facts
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        filters:
            instance-state-name: running
            "tag:Type": datanodes
    register: dn_id

  - name: Verify that the datanodes instance is running...
    local_action:
        module: ec2
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        instance_ids: '{{ item.id }}'
        state: running
        wait: True
        vpc_subnet_id: '{{ vpc_subnet_id }}'
    tags: start    
    register: ec2
    with_items: "{{ dn_id.instances }}"
  - debug: var=ec2

  - name: Gather volume information for dn instance
    local_action:
        module: ec2_vol
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        instance: '{{ item.id }}'
        state: list
    register: volume
    with_items: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances }}"

  - name: tag the volumes with their correct instance IP Address
    local_action: 
        module: ec2_tag 
        resource: '{{ item.1.id }}'
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        tags:
          CurrentIP: '{{ item.0 }}'
          #DeviceName: '{{ item.0 }}'
          #VolumeId: '{{ item.1.volume_id }}'
          #MountName: '{{ item.1.mount }}'
    with_nested:
        - "{{ groups.datanodes }}"      
        - "{{ volume.results[0].volumes }}"

  - name: tag the volumes with the universal volume Id (everyone gets this one)
    local_action: 
        module: ec2_tag 
        resource: '{{ item.0.id }}'
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        tags:
           home_id: '{{ item.1.id }}'
          #CurrentIP: '{{ item.0 }}'
          #DeviceName: '{{ item.0 }}'
          #VolumeId: '{{ item.1.volume_id }}'
          #MountName: '{{ item.1.mount }}'
    with_nested:   
        - "{{ volume.results[0].volumes }}"
        - "{{ volume.results[0].volumes }}"
    when: item.device_name | search("/dev/sd")
```

How would I do this with multiple instances? If you have a better way for the one node that would be great to. Also, I need it to be as dynamic as possible, so I cannot just use `/dev/sdb` and `/mount1` for each name...

Comment: D you want to extend this to multiple hosts? Not sure what you mean by `as dynamic as possible`

Comment: Yes!!!!!! Sorry

Comment: Actually, with multiple ec2 instances rather. That will make it so I can mount volumes with multiple hosts in end.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out for both tagging the actual instance and the volume. However, the volume tagging had its limitations, as it seemed I had to assume that the volume was tagged with it's volume Id in the first place. Still, it does work...

```
  - name: Tag the Volumes with their Correct db Instance IP Address
    local_action: 
        module: ec2_tag 
        resource: '{{ item.tags.VolumeId }}'
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        tags:
          CurrentIP: '{{ item.private_ip_address }}'
          #DeviceName: '{{ item.0 }}'
          #VolumeId: '{{ item.1.volume_id }}'
          #MountName: '{{ item.1.mount }}'
    with_items: "{{ db_id.instances }}"

  - name: Tag the Instances with their Correct db Instance IP Address
    local_action: 
        module: ec2_tag 
        resource: '{{ item.id}}'
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        tags:
          CurrentIP: '{{ item.private_ip_address }}'
          HDeviceName: '{{ home_vol_device }}'
          HMountName: '{{ home_vol_mount_name }}'
    with_items: "{{ db_id.instances }}"
```